# Math equation for graph

Tags: javascript, math, graph, equation

I am working on a graphing class (in javascript) which uses canvas. This is just for experimental / learning purposes. Currently the graph scales correctly based on whatever height and width the canvas is set at. This is not a problem, and here is basically what I am doing to plot the correct coordinates [pseudo-code].

```
point[0] = [10, 15]
point[1] = [20, 10]
point[2] = [30, 20]
point[3] = [40, 15]

canvas width = 300
max x = 40

so for any given point:

position x = ( point[i][0] / max x ) * canvas width
```

simple enough. I get a ratio, then multiply it by the canvas width to plot it at the correct pixel.

The problem however, is coming up with an equation that would cause the minimum value of x to reside at 0 on the x coordinate of the graph, and the max value to be at the maximum point of the graph (which it already does because of the 1:1 ratio in my current equation). Currently the minimum value of x (10 in the example), resides at 75px in the x coordinate, because of the 1:4 ratio being multiplied to the canvas' width.

***tldr / summary:** I need to make a graph in which the minimum value is plotted at the beginning of the graph(0,0), and the maximum value plotted to the end.*

Comment: You need the range of values, scale the axis so that the graph is the size of the range, and scale all values as the (value - min_value) * scale factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try calculating a value for pixel-width-per-point first.

e.g.

```
widthPerPoint =  canvasWidth / (maxX - minX)
```

then your position can be normalised to zero by subtracting the minimum value:

```
position = widthPerPoint * (point[i][0] - minX)
```

for your first example

```
widthPerPoint = 300 / (40 - 10) = 10

position = 10 * (point[i][0] - 10) = 10 * 0 = 0
```

and for the others:

```
  point[0] = [10, 15] -> 0
  point[1] = [20, 10] -> 100
  point[2] = [30, 20] -> 200
  point[3] = [40, 15] -> 300
```

at least I think that'll work....

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over your points and record what you find (sorry, I can't do algorithm programming in JavaScript. pseudo-Python is so much easier):

```
minimum = [infinity, infinity, -1]
maximum = [-infinity, -infinity, -1]

for point in points:
  if point.x > maximum.x and point.y > maximum.y:
    maximum = [point.x, point.y, point.index]

  if point.x < minimum.x and point.y < minimum.y:
    minimum = [point.x, point.y, point.index]

if maximum.index == -1:
  print 'No point is a maximum, so the points all lie in a horizontal line.'

  maximum = [points[0].x, points[0].y, 0]
  minimum = [points[0].x, points[0].y, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question correctly. If so, this is the equation:

```
position x = (point[i][0] - min x) * canvas width / (max x - min x)
```

This way when `point[i][0]` is minimal (`min x`) your value is `0.0.` and when it is maximal (`max x`) the value is `canvas width`, growing linearly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map linearly the range [min_x, max_x] to [0, width]. A point `x = point[i][0]` is mapped to

```
position(x) = width/(max_x - min_x) * (x - min_x).
```